# when fixing bugs, how can I be sure I'm fixing the right bug?

Tags: debugging

So this question is fairly generic and open. I have no specific example to hand right now, but have long been wondering how do most people out there approach bug fixing with regards to root causing the issue, rather than fixing the symptoms?

Comment: This question is far too broad and vague. You fix all bugs you find. You never fix the symptoms; you fix what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious @KenWhite - I think you missed that my question is about how to approach finding the root cause of bugs and not how to fix bugs per se.

Comment: No. I didn't miss it. You asked a very vague, broad question asking for a discussion about ways to debug programs that is not appropriate for this site. I didn't miss that at all.

Comment: I agree on it being broad. Where would a question like this suit within stack exchange?

Comment: There aren't any, AFAIK. There aren't any discussion sites here. You can always ask for advice on a site by posting on [meta.se], and maybe someone there knows of one. I'm pretty aware of all the programming related sites, and I don't know of any for this broad a question.

Comment: A program is a dissertation, full of Inductive reasoning, incorrect premises lead to the hell of miseries, correct ones lead to the heaven of joys. You can tell Heaven from Hell, can you?

Comment: I understand your analogy @jerrychin. what I was hoping is to steer some discussion and hopefully learn some base line of approaches. Despite the fact that telling wrong from right should be obvious, it isn't so necessarily all the times.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to do is create a test case that reproduces the bug, then apply the bug fix to the code. Run the test case again and see if the bug is still present. If it is not, then you may have fixed the bug. Of course, this doesn't address questions such as "Did your bug fix break something else?", "Did you fix bugs related to this one?", etc. These questions may be able to be addressed in part by the quality of the test case that you create, but not necessarily.